# Embedding Subtiles/Captioned Comments in TVML TVOS

Tags: tvos, http-live-streaming, subtitle, m3u8, tvml

I am trying to use the media player that TVML provides to play videos from inside my TVOS app. Everything works fine and the `HLS stream manifest file (m3u8)` I have plays perfectly on the player.

My concern here is how can I add a subtitle file(srt, vtt) to the player. The player seem to extract and build the subtitles automatically from my m3u8 file, but I have separate subtitle files with me for each video item. It seems at the moment I'll have to encode the subtitles file within the m3u8, which would be a overhead considering all other players(HTML5 and android) support external subtitle file and I have more than 1000 video files.

I could not find any documentation for the Player or for the MediaItem in the TVJS to be able to achieve the same. I can't even attach a subtitle to the MediaItem programatically.

I've referenced the following URLS:

[MediaItem TVML Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSMediaItem_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/MediaItem/MediaItem)

[Closed Caption HLS](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/AboutHTTPLiveStreaming/about/about.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013978-CH3-SW15)

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: did you get any solution? Please let me know.

Comment: Not yet. Still waiting for a solution.

Comment: did you get the solution to show close caption in TVML app?

Comment: As mentioned earlier, you can add the subtitles file in m3u8 file itself and the player will take care of playback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems at the moment there is no external subtitle file support.

Probably in future Apple might add the same, but currently we'll have to burn the subtitle files within the m3u8 playlist.

Answer (score 0):

...for PlexConnect (aTV2/aTV3) I once implemented a simple subtitle engine in JS, using video overlay. Not sure if something like this would fit your needs. See https://github.com/iBaa/PlexConnect, files `Subtitle.py` for translating SRT into JSON, plus `Application.js` to actually handle the display.